# Returning view rotation to it's original state after canceling animation in API < 11

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm running shake animation on my view:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="100"
    android:fromDegrees="-5"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toDegrees="5" />
```

I'm canceling animation on user demand, but the view stays rotated as it was in the moment of stopping and I wan't it to back to it's original state.

Here is how I'm stopping the animation:

```
    if (animation != null) {
        animation.cancel();
        animation.reset();
    }
```

I can't use `setRotation()` because my min API is 9.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this method (code is inside the class inheriting from `View`):

```
private void returnToOriginalRotationState() {
    RotateAnimation animation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
    animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animation.setDuration(1);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);

    startAnimation(animation);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `view.clearAnimation()` method, It clears all effects of animation on the view

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `setRotation(0,0f);` ?

EDIT:
I see, this requires API 11 and you need API 9 and above. (There's precious little reason to support API that low in 2014, but OK, we don't always get to dictate that.) Maybe subclass Animation so that when you "cancel" it just animates to a rotation of 0 and then calls super.cancel().

Comment: I can't due to low API

Comment: I see. (There's precious little reason to support API that low, but OK.) Maybe subclass Animation so that when you "cancel" it just animates to a rotation of 0 and then calls super.cancel()...